# Extract one or more qualifying substrings from each string in an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, substring, text-extraction

I am trying to extract qualifying substrings from an array of strings. Some strings in the array have just one qualifying substring, but others may have more.  I need to build a flat array of all of these wanted values.

The following is my current Codeigniter method, but it doesn't handle cases when more than one qualifying substring exists.

```
public function generatenewname()
{
    $this->load->helper('directory');
    $map = directory_map('./assets/file_upload/md/temp/', FALSE, TRUE);
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($map); $x++) {
        $newest[$x] = explode(" ", $map[$x]);
        for ($y = 0; $y < count($newest[$x]); $y++) {
            if (strlen($newest[$x][$y]) >= 7) {
                $file[] = $newest[$x][$y];
            }
        }
    }
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($file); $x++) {
        echo $x . ' ' . $file[$x] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Assume that my `$map` array contains this:

```
$map = [
    'BACK PACK BBP160800103  G086-1 8#.JPG',
    'BACKPACK BBP160500010 G114-3#1.JPG',
    'WSL160800024-WSL160800025 L83-5.JPG',
    'IA041017 L83-5.JPG'
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    'BBP160800103',
    'BBP160500010',
    'WSL160800024',
    'WSL160800025',
    'IA041017'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your final array to this function to achieve your result.

```
arraymakking($file);//your array

function arraymakking($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        if(strpos($val,'-') !== false){
            $res=explode('-',$val);
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
    $result=array_merge($arr,$res);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: did you check this? @YVS1102

Comment: i am exploding the `$val` and storing into the `$res` variable which is array.@YVS1102

Comment: yah my bad . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can match against the patterns based on starting keys.

```
$array = [
    ['BACK', 'PACK', 'BBP160800103', '', 'G086-1', '8#.JPG'],
    ['BACKPACK', 'BBP160500010', 'G114-3#1.JPG'],
    ['WSL160800024-WSL160800025', 'L83-5.JPG'],
    ['IA041017', 'L83-5.JPG']
];

$patterns = ['(BBP\w+)', '(WSL\w+)', '(IA\w+)'];

$codes = [];
$matcher = '/' . implode($patterns, '|') . '/';

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    array_map(function ($value) use ($matcher, &$codes) {
        preg_match_all($matcher, $value, $matches);

        foreach($matches as $match) {
            $codes = array_merge(array_filter($match), $codes);
        }
    }, $arr);
}

print_r(array_unique($codes));

// output
Array
(
    [0] => IA041017
    [2] => WSL160800024
    [3] => WSL160800025
    [6] => BBP160500010
    [8] => BBP160800103
)
```

Comment: when i adding another `$patterns`, it run slow. sorry bad english

Answer (score 0):

More directly than exploding the strings and scavenging through the smitherings, call `preg_match_all()` on the strings to articulately pick out the qualifying substrings, then unpack those one-or-more substrings inside of an `array_push()` call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SjO2O))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($map as $string) {
    array_push($result, ...preg_match_all('/\b(?:BBP|WSL|IA)\d{6,9}\b/', $string, $m) ? $m[0] : []);
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
echo $array[0][3]; //BBP160800103
echo $array[2][1]; //BBP160500010
```

Etc. Refer to the indexing by number. You'd be better off creating your array with named indexes. Like this:

```
$array = array("Array1"=>array("key1"=>"val1","key2"=>"val2"),"Array2"=>(array("2ndKey1"=>"val1", "2ndKey2"=>"val2));
```